# org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource Unable to read content from few websites

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http

We are using `org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource` to read Images from websites.

Following is the replication code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        UrlResource ur = new UrlResource(new URL(
                "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/realistic-baubles-different-designs-hang-600w-1242738214.jpg"));
        System.out.println(ur.isReadable());

        ur = new UrlResource(new URL("https://pngimg.com/uploads/falcon/falcon_PNG30.png"));
        System.out.println(ur.isReadable());
    }

}
```

and the result for this is

```
true
false
```

Comment: In your second case when Java tries to open the connection for this resource - it gets 403 Forbidden - that is why you get false.

Comment: `pngimg.com` is cloduflare protected - you'll need to set a different user agant (see duplicate).